# In matlab plot scatter points as different sized points that cover the x and y error instead of error bars

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I want to plot scatter data with both x and y errors, which I can do this using [`errorbarxy`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19002-errorbarxy) function.

I am wondering, however, if I can use the upper and lower limits of x and y to instead plot the scatter points as different sized semi-transparent points that cover the error 'region' where the error bars would usually cover?

i.e. how can I achieve `scatter(x,y,a,c)` where `a` is the area defined by upper and lower limits in each direction?

My code for the normal `errorbarxy` is:

```
X = 10 * rand(7,1);
Y = 10 * rand(7,1);
ux = rand(7,1);
uy = rand(7,1);
lx = rand(7,1);
ly = rand(7,1);
errorbarxy(X,Y,ux,uy,lx,ly,'Color','k','LineStyle','none','Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','w','MarkerSize',11);
set(gca,'YScale','log');
set(gca,'XScale','log');
```

Note the log scaling.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a scaling of the size of your scatter points you normally subtract the minimum to shift your data to 0, then divide by the maximum to normalise to the interval [0,1]. In this case I'd recommend some increase of interval, say [4,9] to increase the area for visualisation in `scatter`. So for one dimension:

```
X = rand(1e3,1)*8+14; %// some random data to make this example work
X = X-min(X);         %// shift to 0
X = X/max(X);         %// normalise to [0,1]
X = 5*X+4;            %// increase area for visualisation purposes
```